# Associative arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Currently, I am creating a 3d array in js using the following:

```
var arr = [["name1", "place1", "data1"],
          ["name2", "place2", "data2"],
          ["name3", "place3", "data3"]];
```

I can access each element using arr[0] or arr[1]. But is there anyways I can access them using a key like this: arr["name1"] should give me the first one. Any suggestions? I think I am looking for a Hashmap like functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you could do that is by wrapping it in an object.

```
var arr = {
    name1 : ["name1", "place1", "data1"],
    name2 : ["name2", "place2", "data2"],
    name3 : ["name3", "place3", "data3"]
};
```

Comment: @Legend - Don't forget to accept an answer. It will make sure you keep getting quality answers in the future. *Plus it makes me look good. :)*

Comment: Of course... There's a 15 minute time limit to accept answers :)

Answer (score 3):

**The situation has changed in the six years since this question was asked.**

Due to weak typing **associative arrays can be faked** in JavaScript:

```
>> var names = new Array();
undefined

>> names["first"] = "Dotan";
"Dotan"

>> names["last"] = "Cohen";
"Cohen"

>> for ( key in names ) { console.log(key+" "+names[key]) }
undefined
first Dotan
last Cohen
```

That is **sometimes** useful, and all browsers released since 2012 support it, but **there are caveats**! The array **cannot** be simply read back:

```
>> names
Array [  ]
```

More importantly, the array's length **cannot** be easily retrieved:

```
>> names.length
0
```

Therefore this is not an associative array in the sense that JavaScript would have supported it had it been intended, but rather a workaround that is often useful if for whatever reason a real JS object does not support what you need:

```
>> var names = {};
undefined

>> names.first = "Dotan";
"Dotan"

>> names.last = "Cohen";
"Cohen"

>> for ( key in names ) { console.log(key+" "+names[key]) }
undefined
first Dotan
last Cohen

>> names
Object { first: "Dotan", last: "Cohen" }

>> Object.keys(names).length
2
```

Comment: thanks for the update. 6 years after your 6 years after 

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is a prototype based dynamic language. You can create objects and change their structure when you want.

```
var o = {name1: {place1: data1}, name2: {place2: data2}};
```

and access it with:

```
o.name1
```

The look-up implementation varies though and when you have a lot of properties that often changes this can be pretty slow (except in Chrome that uses a special scheme to access object properties i.e. embedded classes a-la-dynamic dispatch from smalltalk). Some libraries (e.g. MooTools) provide some hash map related structures,

Comment: So in this example, to access place1, would you reference it with `o.name1.place1`? and what would that give you? The value `place1` or the value `data1`?