# Does Javascript have associative arrays?

Tags: javascript

Does Javascript have associative arrays? Please explain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Associative arrays in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399550/associative-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6):

Nope; JavaScript arrays are just numeric keys and mixed values. The same thing can be achieved (or, actually, it's exactly the same as associative arrays in other languages) with objects:

```
var foo = {
  a: 123,
  b: 'CDE'
};

foo.a; // 123
foo['a']; // 123
```

You could use arrays:

```
var foo = [];
foo.a = 123;
foo.b = 'CDE';

foo.b; // CDE
foo['b']; // CDE
```

HOWEVER, this should *never* be done because this will not enter the key/value pairs into the array, but add them to the array object as properties. (besides, `{a: 123}` is easier than `a = []; a.a = 123`) If you need key/value pairs, use Objects. If you need an enumerated list, use arrays.

Comment: I am curious why you recommend arrays for enums and Objects for maps. Can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is pretty much a copy-paste of my previous answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399550/associative-arrays-in-javascript/40348206#40348206).

**The situation has changed in the five years since this question was asked.**

Due to weak typing **associative arrays can be faked** in JavaScript:

```
>> var names = new Array();
undefined

>> names["first"] = "Dotan";
"Dotan"

>> names["last"] = "Cohen";
"Cohen"

>> for ( key in names ) { console.log(key+" "+names[key]) }
undefined
first Dotan
last Cohen
```

That is **sometimes** useful, and all browsers released since 2012 support it, but **there are caveats**! The array **cannot** be simply read back:

```
>> names
Array [  ]
```

More importantly, the array's length **cannot** be easily retrieved:

```
>> names.length
0
```

Therefore this is not an associative array in the sense that JavaScript would have supported it had it been intended, but rather a workaround that is often useful if for whatever reason a real JS object does not support what you need:

```
>> var names = {};
undefined

>> names.first = "Dotan";
"Dotan"

>> names.last = "Cohen";
"Cohen"

>> for ( key in names ) { console.log(key+" "+names[key]) }
undefined
first Dotan
last Cohen

>> names
Object { first: "Dotan", last: "Cohen" }

>> Object.keys(names).length
2
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest we have is an object; the easiest way you can define this is using object literal syntax.

```
var assocArray = {
   key: 1,
   key2: 2
};
```

You should be wary of a few things however:

1. It does not have a `.length` property.
2. You should use `for in` to iterative over it, rather than `for(;;;);`, but should combine it with `hasOwnProperty()`:

   ```
   for (var x in assocArray) {
       if (assocArray.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
           // x = the key, assocArray[x] = the value 
       }
   }
   ```
3. There is no concept of ordering/ sorting the members. Whilst all implementations I know of iterate the members in the order they were added, this is not standardised.

Comment: Semicolon after } isn't required

Answer (score 1):

Instead of associative arrays. Javascript has `objects`. `Properties` of an object are addressed using a string.

```
 var obj1 = {};  // declare empty object
 var obj2 = {a: 1, b: 'string', c: [4,5]}; // obj with 3 properties, a, b, and c
        // note that the 'c' property contains an anonymous array 

 alert(obj2.a); // shows 1
 obj2.a = 'another string'; // redefine the 'a' property
 obj2.cookie = 'oatmeal'; // add a new property to the object
 obj2['ice_cream'] = {vendor: 'Beyers', 
                      flavor: 'Chocolate Surprise'}; // add anonymous object as
                           // a new property for the object

 assert(obj2.a === obj2['a']); // two ways to retrieve the value
 var i = 'a'; // using an index varable
 assert(obj2.a === obj2[i]);  // note the i does not have apostrophes around it
```

**See the [Quirksmode docs](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Something comparable in JavaScript is an object.

```
var my_obj = { key : 'value' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure it does (kind of, use objects)

```
var foo = {
      bar: "hello"
}
```

accessible with

```
foo.bar
```