# What's an Associative Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, query-string

I'm trying to understand what an associative array really is and what steps are needed to acquire one. I have seen many explanations that are totally different.

I have tried testing it out on my own but can't seem to really get it in the end.

```
var array = ["one", "two", "three"];
var test = array["one"];
console.log(test);
```

I expected for it to target the index in which the string "one" is in, but an error occurs.

Comment: If you are trying to use a String to get a particular property, you probably mean [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), not an `Array`.

Comment: What's the question here? Are you actually looking for a definition, or a solution to a problem? Why is it tagged with `split` and `query-string`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Associative array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38339531/create-associative-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674922/does-javascript-have-associative-arrays.

Comment: Actually you should call the array this way: `console.log(array[1]);` if you want different behaviour, you could do: `array["one"] = "one"` and then call `array["one"]`: `console.log(array["one"]);`.

Comment: you can append anything to any object (include array). you don't actually increase the length this way.

Answer (score 2):

You are likely looking for a JavaScript Object, what is basically the same as an associative array, dictionary, or map in other languages: It maps strings to values. Unlike [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)s, which use square brackets `[]` for declaration, Objects use curly braces `{}` (*please note that there are some exceptions*).

Try to think of an [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) as an associative array:

```js
const arr = {one: 1, two: 2, three: 3};
console.log(arr['one']);
console.log(arr.one);
```

It is worth noting that `Array`'s in JavaScript are technically objects.

> The JavaScript Array object is a global object that is used in the construction of arrays; which are high-level, list-like objects.

The main difference between `Array`'s and `Object`'s is that `Array`s are numerically indexed.

```js
const arr = ['fooValue', 'barValue'];
const obj = {foo: 'fooValue', bar: 'barValue'};

console.log('arr: ', arr[0], arr[1]);
console.log('obj: ', obj.foo,  obj.bar);
```

It is worth noting, that unlike primitive types in JavaScript, `Object`'s (and `Array`'s, which are also `Object`'s) are passed by reference, so extra care is needed when attempting to copy the object.

```js
function test(obj) {
  obj['oops'] = 'this will modify the object';
}

const obj = {one: 1, two: 2, three: 3};
test(obj);
console.log(obj); // Object was updated
```

To avoid accidentally mutating your object, you will have to create a new instance of the object before performing operations on it. There are multiple ways to accomplish this:

- [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)/[spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) you object `let obj2 = {...obj};`
- Using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to understand what an associative array really is...

JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays in the sense that, for instance, PHP does. JavaScript has:

- Arrays, which are (effectively) numerically indexed (see [my blog post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html) for why I said "effectively")
- Objects, which are collections of properties that have names, which are either strings or Symbols (and which have other features, like inheritance)
- Maps, which are collections of key/value pairs where the keys can be any type (not just strings or Symbols)

#### Arrays

To find the index of an entry in an array, typically you use `indexOf` (for an `===` match) or `findIndex` if you want to provide a predicate function.

```js
var array = ["one", "two", "three"];
console.log(array.indexOf("one")); // 0
```

#### Objects

If you wanted, you could create an object that mapped strings to numbers:

```js
var obj = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "forty-two": 42};
console.log(obj["forty-two"]); // 42
```

#### Maps

Similarly, a Map could do that:

```js
var map = new Map([
    ["one", 1],
    ["two", 2],
    ["forty-two", 42]
]);
console.log(map.get("forty-two")); // 42
```

Answer (score 1):

Associative arrays are used to associate something throughout an array.
You can use this with the query string for example:

In order to attain the information from a forum submitted, you need to put the user data into an associative array.

You would start by getting the query string as follows:

```
var queryString = window.location.search;
queryString = queryString.substring(1);
```

The reason why I did substring(1) is so we could remove the '?' at the beginning.

Once you have the query string of the website, you'd need a loop to separate the values of data received:

```
while (queryString.indexOf("+") != -1)
    queryString = queryString("+", " ");
```

This will replace all the '+' signs in the string to spaces, making you get the values without the '+' signs. You'll have "Name=John" for example.

Now we need to split the '&'s from the string. 
We also need to make an array ready for the data from the user.

```
var array = queryString.split("&");
var userData = [];
```

Afterwards, make a for loop in order to target however amount of data submitted and to attain it individually while storing it into the array:

```
for (let x = 0; x < array.length; x++) 
{
    var equalSign = array[x].search("=");
    var theKeyValue = array[x].substring(0, equal);
    var userDataValue = array[x];
    userDataValue = decodeURIComponent(userDataValue); //Puts symbols back
    userData[theKeyValue] = userDataValue;
}
```

This is just an example to follow up with the usage of associative arrays, hopefully this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

An associative array is a data structure, a data collection, which has the scope of associate a list of key to respective values (key: value).

You can read in Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), that are example of associative array for example: Map, Dictionary, etc.

Sample of associative array are also PHP indexed array, e.g.:

```
$cars[0] = "Volvo"; 
$cars[1] = "BMW";
$cars[2] = "Toyota";
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array).

It is a data structure when you can look up a value by a key. This is typically implemented in JS using a `Map` or an `Object`.

```js
const data = new Map([
    ['foo', 'one'],
    ['bar', 'two']
]);

console.log( data.get("bar") );
```

---

> I expected for it to target the index in which the string "one" is in, but an error occurs.

You are attempting to look up the index of a property in an array by its value.

That has nothing to do with associative arrays and is achieved with the `indexOf` method.

```js
var array = ["one", "two", "three"];
var test = array.indexOf("one");
console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

An associative array, is essentially a hashmap, or an array that associates relationships.

For example if I was to build an associative array for fruits let's say to prices it would look like.

```
const arr = {'apple': 1, 'orange': 2, 'pear': 3};

console.log(Object.keys(arr));
console.log(Object.values(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other languages, array in Javascript are not limited by having only numeric indices. They can act as hashes as well (i.e. having a string as a key). An associative array is one where you set the key to be a non-numeric value.

By default, and in the example you provided, ascending numeric values are assigned to each member of the array. I.e.

```
var array = ["one", "two", "three"];
```

is equivalent to

```
var array = [];
array[0] = 'one';
array[1] = 'two';
array[2] = 'three';
```

An associative array would be one where instead of numeric values you assign a different value:

```
var array = [];
array['one'] = 'one';
array['two'] = 'two';
```

However this brings a few caveats in itself and it considered bad practice and the arrays become harder to manage. In cases like there it would be better to use either an object or a `Map`.

Answer (score -1):

That's not an associative array, that's just a regular array, filled with text.

An associative array example (you can also use object syntax like Miroslav's answer):

```
var stuff = [];
stuff['one'] = "hello 1";
stuff['two'] = "hello 2";
```