# Javascript array in php style

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Associative arrays in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399550/associative-arrays-in-javascript)

Is it possible to do in javascript something like this:

```
array('one' => 'value-1','two'=> 'value-2');
```

And after that access it like this `$var['one']` and to return `value-1` I'm kinda new to JS, and google didn't gave me a good answer.

Comment: the proper term for that type of array is an "associative array" which will provide much more information on Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no - you can create an **object** like this:

```
var theObject = { one: "value 1", two: "value 2" };
```

but it's not an array.  True arrays in JavaScript have strictly numeric indexes. (You can add string-named properties to a JavaScript array object, but they're not accounted for in the `.length` of the array.)

*edit* — to add properties to the object (or any object), you can use the `.` or `[]` operators:

```
theObject.newProperty = "something new";

theObject[ computeNewPropertyName() ] = "wow";
```

The second example shows the `[]` operator, which is used when the name of a property is computed dynamically some how (in the example, by a function call, but it could be any expression).

Comment: and if I want later to add new items to the object, how do I do it? let's say that I have one,two in the object already, and I want to add  five,six to the object, but in other part of the code, how do I do it?

Comment: @Uffo: You can use `theObject.five = '5'` or `theObject['five'] = '5'`.

Comment: @Uffo I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it's called an object:

```
var your_object = {
    'one': 'value-1',
    'two': 'value-2'
};
```

Answer (score 2):

hah))) in normal languages this is called a dictionary))) In javascript you can  create dictionary or object like this

```
    a = {"one":"value-1", "two":"value-2"}
```

a["one"] returns "value-1"

Answer (score 1):

Try

Array (an ordered, indexed set of items) :

```
var myArray = [
    'value-1',
    'value-2'
];
```

Object (an orderless set of keyed properties):

```
var myObject = {
    'one': 'value-1',
    'two': 'value-2'
};
```